# An unclear sentence in the book "Griffiths, Harris-Principles of algebraic geometry"

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, curvature, connections, complex-manifolds

Let $X$ be a complex manifold and consider a holomorphic vector bundle $\pi:E\to X$ of rank $r$. By the usual correspondence between vector bundles and locally free sheaves, we consider $E$ as a sheaf by abuse of notation. We denote with $\mathscr A_X^{p,q}$ the sheaf of $C^\infty$ $(p,q)$-differential forms on $X$ and we define:
$$A^{p,q}(E):=\Gamma(X,\mathscr A^{p,q}\otimes_{\mathscr O_X} E)$$
$$A^k(E):=\bigoplus_{p+q=k}A^{p,q}(E)$$

Now suppose that $\nabla:A^\bullet(E)\to A^\bullet(E)$ is a linear connection on $E$, then the curvature operator is defined as:
$$\nabla^2:A^0(E)\to A^2(E)$$
where $\nabla^2$ is the composition of the maps $\nabla: A^0(E)\to A^2(E)$   and $\nabla: A^1(E)\to A^2(E)$. One can show that $\nabla^2$ is $C^\infty(X)$-linear.

---

I don't understand the following sentence from the Griffiths-Harris book at page 75 (I rephrase it by using my notation):

> Since $\nabla^2$ is $C^\infty(X)$-linear, then it is induced by a bundle map $E\to\bigwedge^2T^*X\otimes E$, or in other words, $\nabla^2$ corresponds to a global section $\Theta$ of the bundle $\bigwedge^2T^*X\otimes\operatorname{Hom}(E,E)$.

I absolutely don't understand how I can see the operator $\nabla^2$ as the section $\Theta$.

Comment: I'm a bit stuck on this page as well, but on the calculation of $D^2(f \cdot \sigma)$ at the top. The first term $-df \wedge D \sigma$ is fine, but how do we know how $D$ behaves on the $E$-valued 1-form $f \cdot D \sigma$? In order to apply the Leibniz rule that defines $D$ on this space, it seems we would have to isolate the 1-form part of $f D\sigma$ from the "section of $E$" part...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $E$, $F$ be two smooth vector bundles over a smooth manifold $X$. A linear map $L : \Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(F)$ is $C^{\infty}(X)$-linear if and only if there is a vector bundle homomorphism $\sigma : E \to F$, i.e. $\sigma \in \Gamma (\operatorname{Hom}(E, F))$, such that $L(s) = \sigma\circ s$ for all $s \in \Gamma(E)$. A proof can be found in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (second edition), Lemma 10.29 where is goes by the name 'Bundle Homomorphism Characterization Lemma'.

In this case $F = \bigwedge^2T^*X\otimes E$. To complete the identification, note that $\operatorname{Hom}(E, F) \cong E^*\otimes F$ and hence

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Hom}\left(E, \bigwedge\nolimits^2T^*X\otimes E\right) &\cong E^*\otimes \bigwedge\nolimits^2T^*X\otimes E\\ 
&\cong \bigwedge\nolimits^2T^*X\otimes E^*\otimes E\\ 
&\cong \bigwedge\nolimits^2T^*X\otimes \operatorname{Hom}(E, E).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much, but I have the last question: why  $\Gamma(\text{Hom }(E,\wedge^2 T^\ast M\otimes E))=\Gamma(\wedge^2 T^\ast M\otimes \text{Hom }(E,E))$?

Comment: @manifold: I have edited my answer to indicate how to do this. Let me know if this is still unclear.